# border radius is not applying to an unordered list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, border

I am trying to apply border radius attribute in an unordered list that I created. I will use the list as a navigation bar. Other CSS attributes are working except the border. I am developing it with a microsoft visual studio 2008 as an aspx file. I am also using this with Twitter Bootstrap front-end framework. What I did with the list is this:

```
#nav, #nav ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style-type:none;
list-style-position:outside;
position:relative;
line-height:1.5em; 
 z-index: 300;
}
    #nav li:first-child, li:last-child{

        border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    }
#nav a
{
    border-style: none outset none none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #333;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #1B5795;
}
```

and this is my code:

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Am I doing something that is preventing the border-radius attribute to work?

Comment: you want to border on each `li` or first or last one have rounded corners? Looking for this? http://jsbin.com/bafokapu/1/edit

Comment: @KheemaPandey yes I am trying to add rounded corners to the first and last list item, but since I have also tried earlier to use the border-radius on all of my list items and its not working.

Comment: so my example works for you? `border-radius` property works for all latest browsers. Prefix are required like `-moz` or `-webkit` for older browsers.

Comment: @KheemaPandey yeah but actually I just found out that the anchor CSS is interfering with the list item. So either way it now works.

Answer (score 1):

Need a little change at css

```
    #nav a
{
    border-style: none outset none none;
    border:1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #1B5795;
}
```

it works on me

Comment: hmm, if the syntax is ok, is it possible if microsoft visual studio is affecting the list?

Comment: I think that can be Bootstrap too.Sometimes Bootstraps override our CSS